# how do I change an array inside a structure inside a private class?(c++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, private

This has just turned into a flame war. I will ask the question again later if I dont figure it out.

The values are changed inside the function, but once the function ends the values go back to what they were set to originally.

```
class inventory
 {
private:
struct instock {

    double everything[4]; //Gets set to 0-3. Then user changes values.

};

public:
instock stock;
void changegas(double userinput);
void stocking(); //populates the array
void output();  //outputs the array
};
```

.

```
void inventory::stocking(){
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    stock.everything[i]=i;
 }
}

void inventory::changegas(double input){
double a;
a = input;
stock.everything[0] += a;
std::cout << "Gas remaining: " << stock.everything[0];
}

void inventory::output(){
std::cout << std::endl;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
 std::cout << stock.everything[i];
 }
}

void inventory::changegas(double input){
double a;
a = input;
stock.everything[0] += a;
std::cout << "Gas remaining: " << stock.everything[0];
}
```

How can I make it so this function changes the value of the array stored in everything permanently?

```
   int main()
{


backroom.stocking();

int choice;

cout << "What would you like to change? \n1.)Gas\n2.)Tires\n3.)Soda\n4.)Snacks"<<endl;
cin >> choice;
menu(choice, backroom);
backroom.output();




return 0;
}

void menu(int zed, inventory a){
 int z = zed;
 int c = 0;
switch (z){//start switch

case 1:
    cout << "Enter the amount of Gas you want to change: ";
    cin >> c;
    a.changegas(c);
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "Enter the amount of Tires you want to change: ";
    cin >> c;
    a.changetires(c);
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "Enter the amount of Soda you want to change: ";
    cin >> c;
    a.changesoda(c);
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "Enter the amount of Snacks you want to change: ";
    cin >> c;
    a.changesnacks(c);
    break;

    break;
}//endswitch

}// end funct
```

I know arrays are passed by reference so I thought this would work as is. But clearly I am not understanding something correctly. Still currently learning the language. 
Maybe I am not passing the array properly?

Comment: What are your particular problems/expectations with the input/output? Elaborate (**edit your question!!**), it's pretty unclear what you're asking for!

Comment: http://ideone.com/CKPqGB

Comment: the `bar` in the `foo::changebar` is indeed `this->bar`. So the values should be changed. There is no thing relevant with where the `struct problem` is declared.

Comment: Well.. deleted my answer.. some idiot decided to downvote for no reason.. Anyway, just see the ideone link. Nothing is wrong with your code. The value of bar does change.

Comment: Ok, something must be wrong somewhere else. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3196093 You aren't calling foo::changebar.  Do you have another changebar function that isn't in a class?

Comment: Well, since you have shown some efforts in clarifying and editing your answer, I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: Thanks, do you see any flaws in my code? I keep running it through the debugger and seeing the values of the array change, then reset to default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing backroom by value.  You need to alter `menu()` to take in either an inventory reference or an inventory pointer, preferably the former.  This is because when you pass a class object by value, the entire object is copied to a new instance local to the function being called and any changes made to that instance will not effect the original copy.

This should work:

```
void menu(int zed, inventory& a) {
    int z = zed; //you don't need this by the way
    int c = 0;

    switch (z){//start switch
    case 1:
        cout << "Enter the amount of Gas you want to change: ";
        cin >> c;
        a.changegas(c);
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Enter the amount of Tires you want to change: ";
        cin >> c;
        a.changetires(c);
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Enter the amount of Soda you want to change: ";
        cin >> c;
        a.changesoda(c);
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Enter the amount of Snacks you want to change: ";
        cin >> c;
        a.changesnacks(c);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I would give you a +1 if I could.